# How do we pronounce the 's' after the d in a word?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

For example: *words, foods, goods, etc.*

And if without the 's', how would the 'd' in those words be pronounced? Would it be pronounced like voiced /d/ or unvoiced /d/?

Answer (score 0):

The 's' in those words is pronounced /z/ and the 'd' is pronounced /d/ (i.e., voiced).